# Why does Mathematica return a Fourier transform for a function for which it is not defined?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

The following function

$$g(x) = (1 + x^{1/a} )^a $$

should NOT have a Fourier transform, as far as I am aware, for any real values of $a$ since $g(x)$ is not nice in the sense of decays quickly enough to $0$ at infinity. However, doing:

```
g[x_, a_] := (1 + x^(1/a))^(a);
Plot[g[x, 2], {x, 0, 1000}]
FourierTransform[g[x, 2], x, ω]
```

*Mathematica* somehow comes up with the result:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) (\left| \omega \right| -\omega )}{\omega  \left| \omega \right| ^{3/2}}$$

What is going on here?

Comment: I get the same (which doesn't agree with `Integrate[g[x, 2] Exp[i x \[Omega]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`)  on 9.0.1.

Comment: Well, this seems like a bug in V9.0.1

Comment: @RunnyKine I get the same on 8.0.4 and 7.0.1 as well.

Comment: @b.gatessucks. Interesting. Well, then I guess this is one of those sleeping bugs in *Mathematica* similar to the `Eigenvector` bug discovered recently.

Comment: Consider this one: `FourierTransform[x, x, \[Omega]]` This gives a DiracDelta[ \[Omega] ] function -- is this the same issue? When you do `Integrate[x Exp[i x \[Omega]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` it says the integral does not converge.

Comment: Also, I get this result for FourierTransform[x, x, \[Omega]]. Surely this can't be a bug?

Comment: is it possible that the generalised fourier transform is being computed?

Comment: I do not know whether or not the result is correct, but it is computing the FT in the sense of generalized functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature

Exact integration returns

```
1/Sqrt[2 Pi]
  Integrate[(1 + Sqrt[x])^2 Exp[I k x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals}]
```

> Integrate::idiv: "Integral of E^(I\k\x)\ (1+[Sqrt]x)^2 does not converge on {-Infinity,Infinity}."

However we can multiply by `Exp[-b Abs[x]]` and then put `b -> 0`

```
Limit[1/Sqrt[2 Pi]
   Integrate[(1 + Sqrt[x])^2 E^(I k x)
     E^(-b Abs[x]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals, b > 0}], b -> 0]
```

[image]

```
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals}]
```

[image]

Comment: ok - clever thanks. So as a feature it applies a damping factor. This is a quite close to the FourierTransform[] result but not the same I think. In particular the root 2 has somehow dropped out.

Comment: Sorry. To follow up on this last comment the difference between your direct approach and the FourierTransform[] result is due to a different definition of the transform. But ... the result only applies to positive k ?

Comment: @LuapNalehw I think results are exactly the same. For this I gave the simplified form.

Comment: sorry I didn't see  your 1/Sqrt[2 Pi]. You are right. I don't see how the simplified form is working out though. For example, at $k = 2$ I get $(1+i) / 16 i$

Comment: Seemingly Mathematica is able to compute Fourier transforms for (tempered) distributions...